# Powershell Error Handling and Null results

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the AD Groups that don't have a manager but have "Approval" in the notes field. I need the report to output both in the same data set.

The issue is, the script below is only returning the AD Groups that have managers assigned but not the null results where Approval is in the notes field.

The current output looks like this

```
Group Name        Managed By       Managed By Email                        
----------        ----------       ----------------                        
ADGroup1          ManagerName1    ManagerName1@domain.com
```

and I need report to include the groups that have Approval in the notes field and that report would ideally look like this.  This is assuming that ADGroup2 doesn't have a manager assigned but Approval is in the notes field.

```
Group Name        Managed By       Managed By Email                        
----------        ----------       ----------------                        
ADGroup1          ManagerName1    ManagerName1@domain.com
ADGroup2
```

The script runs just doesn't return the "null" results.

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter 'GroupCategory -eq "Security"' -Properties ManagedBy | where-object {($_.ManagedBy -gt 0 -and $_.ManagedBy -ne $null -and $_.ManagedBy -notlike "*Organization Management*") -or ($_.Notes -like "*Approval*")} |
ForEach-Object { 
$managedBy = IF([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.managedBy)) {""} else {$_.managedBy};

$manager = (get-aduser -Identity $managedBy -Properties emailAddress);
$managerName = $manager.Name;
$managerEmail = $manager.emailAddress;

Write-Output $_; } | 
Select-Object @{n='Group Name';e={$_.Name}}, @{n='Managed By';e={$managerName}}, @{n='Managed By Email';e={$managerEmail}} | Sort-Object "Managed By", "Group Name"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The real name for the "notes" field is `info`, and you're not including it in your `Get-ADGroup -Properties`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute backing the multiline field rendered as "Notes" in Active Directory Users and Computers is a [Comment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms676199(v=vs.85).aspx) - to make the confusion total, the LDAP Display Name of said attribute is `info`:

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter "GroupCategory -eq 'Security'" -Properties ManagedBy,info
$ApprovalGroups = $Groups |Where-Object {$_.info -like "*Approval*"}
```

That being said, I'd probably attempt to turn most of the conditions into a single LDAP search filter:

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(&(info=*Approval*)(managedBy=*)(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483648))" | Where-Object {$_.ManagedBy -notlike "*Organization Management*"}
```

Comment: That got me where I needed to go!